# Ubuntu trusty format disk slower than RHEL7?

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, performance, disk

I observed that disk formatting is much slower in Ubuntu than in RHEL7. Does anybody know why that is?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I'm formatting the disk with ext4. Using mke2fs

Comment: ??what tool are you using.  Is it the installer?

Comment: RHEL7 defaults to XFS, while Ubuntu defaults to ext4. Are you sure you're comparing apples to apples?